# CMD - openning app as user

Tags: command-line, vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to lauch outlook with CMD with simple script I have made. Problem becomes when I open this script on user's computer via CMD ran as admin (my user account) it will open me outlook as I would be opening it now user. So my inbox will apper not user. Script works perfectly if I just run it from normal cmd not elevated mode.

How do I make sure that from elevated CMD it will open me user's inbox not user's that has elvated CMD?

```
strPath = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")
outlook15 = strPath & "\Microsoft Office\Office15\outlook.exe"
outlook14 = strPath & "\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe"

If fso.FileExists(outlook15) Then 
   msgbox "TITUS successfully fixed!", 64
   WScript.Sleep 3000
   WshShell.Run Chr(34) & outlook15 & Chr(34)
   Set fso = Nothing
   Set WshShell = Nothing
Else
   msgbox "TITUS successfully fixed!", 64
   WScript.Sleep 3000
   WshShell.Run Chr(34) & outlook14 & Chr(34)
   Set fso = Nothing
   Set WshShell = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect the current user running CMD you can grab the output from the whoami command like this:

```
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("whoami")
strUser = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
```

Then you can add runas to the WshShell.Run statement to change the user context:

```
If strUser = "admin" Then
    WshShell.Run "runas /user:" & otherUser & " " & Chr(34) & outlook15 & Chr(34)
End If
```

The other username will need to be supplied, either through an input prompt, or it can be captured from another command(qwinsta, psloggedon, etc) and extracted via regex.  It also should be noted that runas will prompt for the other user's password.